# Which is the minimum version of git to run composer?

Tags: php, git, composer-php

I have a website hosted and I want to use composer to resolve my project dependencies on production. But everytime I run composer update I get this error:

```
 $
 [RuntimeException]  
 Failed to execute git status --porcelain --untracked-files=no                                    
 error: unknown option `porcelain'
```

I got the conclusion: git's version on host is too old and it cant recognize `--porcelain` option.

**So, I need update git on host but for what version? What is it the minimum version I can update git to run composer without any issue?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--porcelain` option has been added to `git status` in [git 1.7.0-rc0, commit 6f15787](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6f15787181a163e158c6fee1d79085b97692ac2f) in September 2009.

So you need at least a git 1.7+.